# ImportError: cannot import name 'QPrinter' from 'PyQt5'

Tags: pyqt5, importerror, qprinter

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5 import QPrinter

import sqlite3
```

when running this error shows:  ImportError: cannot import name 'QPrinter' from 'PyQt5'
any help please

Comment: Typo: 1) remove `from PyQt5 import QPrinter`. 2) add `printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()`. QPrinter is not a submodule but a class that belongs to the QtPrintSupport submodule

Comment: thanks for replying....it solved that problem but now its showing      self.previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer,self)
NameError: name 'QPrintPreviewDialog' is not defined......any help please

Comment: Use QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPrinter` is a class inside `QtPrintSupport`, instead import like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
```

Comment: Try installing this package

`> pip install pyqt5-tools   `

Comment: @VinamraJaiswal change `QPrintSupport` to `QtPrintSupport`